# How are parameters in inflation potential determined

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

This is a question on how to determine the parameters in a given inflation potential. I have been studying a particular inflation model (https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.09483) which works with a potential of the form

$$ V(\varphi)=V_{0}\left[ \tanh(\varphi/\sqrt{6})+A\sin\left( \tanh(\varphi/\sqrt{6})/f_{\phi} \right) \right]^2 $$
They determined the parameters to be $A=0.130364,f_{\phi}=0.129551,V_{0}=2\times10^{-10}$. How were these parameters determined? I know that we need to take into consideration the slow roll nature of inflation and power spectrum at the pivot scale, but some details will really help.

Comment: I am impressed by the accuracy of $A$/$f_{\phi}$ and crudeness of $V_0$. It reminds me of a joke: Some tourists in the Museum of Natural History are marveling at some dinosaur bones. One of them asks the guard, "Can you tell me how old the dinosaur bones are?" 

The guard replies, "They are 3 million, four years, and six months old." 

"That's an awfully exact number," says the tourist. "How do you know their age so precisely?" 

The guard answers, "Well, the dinosaur bones were three million years old when I started working here, and that was four and a half years ago."

Comment: It doesn't answer the question though.